# Ubuntu 12.04 server resolution

Tags: resolution

12.04 64 bit server edition in HP ProLiant ML350e server. In that given resolution only 1600x900 in x-desktop. I want to increase the resolution to 1920x1080. My HP ProDisplay P221 will support 1920x1080.

Comment: And the graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I change my screen resolution from

System Settings > Displays

There you should find a tool that changes screen resolution.

You can search in dash to find system settings or you can simply click on the top most right button and click on system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo  /etc/default/grub
```

and then change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vga=NUMBER"
```

where NUMBER is your desired resolution. IE 600, 765, 1080

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Edit: If you mess up, remember your IP and ssh to revert.